# Showing a progress bar in Shiny with variables

Tags: r, shiny

Im playing around with the progress bars in Shiny. For the actual Shiny Application that I am developing im scraping tweets. And - because this takes a long time - I want to inform users by a progress bar. I made a small reproducable example that outlines my problem:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  test_function <- function(city){
    return(city)
  }

  observeEvent(input$show, {
    withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = 0, {
      cities <- c("Amsterdam", "London", "Paris", "Toronto")
      counter = 1

      for (city in length(cities)) {
        progress = counter / length(cities)
        city <- test_function(city)
        incProgress(progress, detail = paste("Scraping city: ", city))
        Sys.sleep(1)
        counter = counter + 1
      }
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I am looking for is a progress bar that - per second - shows another city:

"Scraping Amsterdam"
"Scraping London"

etc...

And the progress bar should fill based on the city (so london is 2/4 -> 50%). However when I run code above I only get "Scraping city 4".

Any thoughts on the tweaks I should make to get the result I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a prettier progress bar have a look at the `shinyWidgets` package:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(4,progressBar(id = "pb4", value = 0, display_pct = T)),
  actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")

)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$show, {
    maxi <- 50
    for (i in 1:maxi) {
      updateProgressBar(session = session, id = "pb4", value = (i/maxi)*100)
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I trust this is what you are after:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  test_function <- function(city){
    return(city)
  }

  observeEvent(input$show, {
    withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = 0, {
      cities <- c("Amsterdam", "London", "Paris", "Toronto")

      for (i in 1:length(cities)) {
        progress = (i-1) / length(cities)
        city <- test_function(cities[i])
        incProgress(progress, detail = paste("Scraping city: ", city))
        Sys.sleep(1)
      }
    })
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

the main problem was  `for (city in length(cities))` since `length(cities)` returns 4 hence just the 4th city was shown.

Additionally the counter should start at 0 (i-1). Since when it starts at 1 the progress bar jumps to 25% iimmediately and ends just when the last city start.

Not a big deal with many cities, but with just 4 it is very noticeable.

the server can also look like this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  test_function <- function(city){
    return(city)
  }

  observeEvent(input$show, {
    withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = 0, {
      cities <- c("Amsterdam", "London", "Paris", "Toronto")
      counter = 0

      for (i in cities) {
        progress = counter / length(cities)
        city <- test_function(i)
        incProgress(progress, detail = paste("Scraping city: ", city))
        Sys.sleep(1)
        counter = counter + 1
      }
    })
  })

}
```